# Time conversion with ptypes.Timestamp vs timestamppb.Timestamp.AsTime

Tags: go, time, protocol-buffers

Since starting to use protocol buffers in `go` I've considered the idiomatic way of converting a `timestamppb.Timestamp` struct to a `time.Time` struct to be via [`ptypes.Timestamp`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#Timestamp), e.g.:

```
t, err := ptypes.Timestamp(pbTimestamp)
if err != nil {
    // some error handling
}
```

However, as I've just discovered, `timestamppb.Timestamp` also has the member function [`AsTime`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp.AsTime) which facilitates the same conversion, while only returning a `time.Time` value and no `error`.

As `ptypes.Timestamp` does return an error on top of the `time.Time`, this suggests that there is the potential for failure, and I was wondering whether the usage of `AsTime` can be considered safe. From the godocs it would seem that there is nothing to consider, but the not returning of an error for the conversion seems somewhat strange. Does anyone by any chance have an explanation for this?

Comment: as the doc says you have to call for IsValid before calling AsTime https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb . Besides that it seems relatively safe  https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/master/types/known/timestamppb/timestamp.pb.go#L197

Comment: Oh, I'm blind, didn't even see `IsValid` and `CheckValid`... From https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/timestamp.go#L36 it seems the error also comes from a validity check. I guess this means if one goes the recommended way there's an error check for both

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** you can't skip the validation check.

---

The problem here is caused by a difference in the semantics of the zero values.

- A zero [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) value:

> [...] is January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC. As this time is unlikely to come up in practice, the IsZero method gives a simple way of detecting a time that has not been initialized explicitly.

- A zero `timestamppb.Timestamp` is the zero **epoch**, i.e. Jan. 1st, 1970 at midnight UTC.

This means that a zero `timestamppb.Timestamp` maps to a valid non-zero `time.Time`. As a matter of fact:

```
(*timestamppb.Timestamp)(nil).AsTime().IsZero() // FALSE!
```

whereas:

```
timestamppb.New(time.Time{}).AsTime().IsZero() // true
```

This is why the old [`ptypes.Timestamp`](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/timestamp.go#L38) function could return an error. It had a validation step baked in, to account for cases where the proto timestamp is invalid — e.g. if it's `nil`. Therefore do not use [`AsTime`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp.AsTime) as a direct replacement for `ptypes.Timestamp`

Use `IsValid` or `CheckValid` instead, and then `AsTime`:

```
if myProtoTs.IsValid() {
    t := myProtoTs.AsTime()
    // do something with t
}
```

Further reading, with comments from the proto maintainers: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1457